# What's the purpose of the "encryptionPolicy"

Tags: android-management-api

In my device policy, there is a property called "encryptionPolicy" ([ref](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#encryptionpolicy))

What is the purpose of this policy on the device?
How do I verify that it was applied?

There are 3 possibilities of values for this policy:

- ENCRYPTION_POLICY_UNSPECIFIED
- ENABLED_WITHOUT_PASSWORD
- ENABLED_WITH_PASSWORD

But I don't know how to verify the application of that.

Answer (score 0):

EncryptionPolicy is used to determined if [encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption) for the device should be enforced.
The level of encryption required to remain compliant depends on the  value set by the policy [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#encryptionpolicy)

ENCRYPTION_POLICY_UNSPECIFIED - (default) This value is ignored, i.e. no encryption required
ENABLED_WITHOUT_PASSWORD - Encryption required but no password required to boot
ENABLED_WITH_PASSWORD - Encryption required with password required to boot

If the device fails to comply to the policy set or if the device’s encryption state does not match with the encryptionPolicy by [default compliance rule](https://developers.google.com/android/management/compliance#default_compliance_rules) android device policy will immediately block usage of the device or work profile by default.

To check the encryption state of your device remotely, you can use device reports (specifically [encryptionStatus](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#EncryptionStatus)).

To verify that if your device is encrypted locally on your android device (depending on your android device) you need to go to settings > security > encryption and credentials , and check the status if it is encrypted

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
Maybe I wasn't clear in my question.
What I would like to know is, besides looking at settings > security > encryption... How can I prove that my device is encrypted?
Connecting a USB cable and trying to access data?

Comment: You can also check it remotely by using [enterprises.devices.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get), and check the status of [encryptionStatus](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#encryptionstatus) on your device